# How do I add data to the DataTable?

Tags: c++-cli

How do I add data to a DataTable which has 5 Columns?

I'm using C++ (CLI).

Comment: What is the "datatable"? Could you elaborate a bit on the technology used. Is this a .NET datatable?

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325587(VS.71).aspx)

```
void AddRow(DataTable^ myTable){
    DataRowCollection^ rc; 
    DataRow^ myNewRow;
    // Create an array with three elements.
    Object rowVals[] = gcnew Object[3];
    rc = myTable->Rows;
    rowVals[0] = S"hello";
    rowVals[1] = S"world";
    rowVals[2] = S"two";
    // Add and return the new row.
    myNewRow = rc->Add(rowVals);
 }
```

You'd need to add two new values to rowVals and then you're away with it
(P.S. I changed the syntax to cli syntax by eye, it might not compile exactly as it is but should be enough to work with)